# java count the times String argument is stored in a Object

Tags: java

for the method `public int count(String str)`
How can I `return` the `number of times` that String argument `str` is stored in an Object?

I have written the following code but I think it is not suppose to do this.

```
public int count(String str)
{
  int count = 0;
  // if the Object contains str
  if(contains(str)) {
    count++;
  else {
    add(str); //add str to Object
    count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

When I typed in command line, eg "test" the `count` is `1`. but when i typed "test" again,
the `count` remains `1`. (it should suppose be `2`).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Then declare the `count` variable as global.

Answer (score 1):

Your method can never return anything but 1, since you initialize `count = 0` each time you run it.

Make `count` a class variable instead of a local variable, so that it will maintain its value between invocations of the method.

Comment: so basically i do `private int count = 0` for class variable, calling it to `count` method and then doing the `count`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "calling it to count method", but yes, if you declare count as `private int count = 0;` in your class, and remove the `int count = 0;` from your method, it will maintain the value of count between invocations of your `count()` method.

Comment: such a small changes make a huge difference... I overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare it as a global variable.
The statement **int count = 0;** resets the variable value to 0. Hence when again tested it updates from 1 to 0 and again to 0.That should be the problem.